# How to suppress the annoying gmapping messages (related to laser scans)?

Tags: navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Whenever I launch gmapping (even without the option output="screen"), I still get the annoying messages, such as:

> Registering Scans:Done

> Laser Pose= 0.886656 -0.155651 2.77905

> Registering Scans:Done

> Laser Pose= 0.886656 -0.155651 2.77905

This is a bit annoying since it fills up the screen with that info. Does anyone know how to suppress these messages?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10294/how-to-suppress-the-annoying-gmapping-messages-(related-to-laser-scans)?/) by [ubuntuslave](https://answers.ros.org/users/631/ubuntuslave/) on ROS Answers with karma: 347 on 2011-06-17

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

They are direct printouts to stderr. You could redirect stderr, but the proper way would be to exchange the calls to ROS_INFO/ROS_DEBUG in the source.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ubuntuslave](https://answers.ros.org/users/631/ubuntuslave/) on 2011-06-21**:
printouts to stderr? Does this mean that these scans are erroneous? Why would gmapping output to stderr unless there is a problem?

**Comment by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) on 2011-06-20**:
I'd happily accept a patch that disables those prints or converts them to ROS_* macro calls (the latter would mean building `gmapping` itself against part of ROS, which is a little strange, but should work).

**Comment by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) on 2012-05-08**:
One informal unix convention (violated by rosconsole, unfortunately) is that stderr is for all logging and diagnostic information, not just errors, while stdout is only for actual "output", e.g., stuff that might potentially be piped to another program.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To expand on what dornhege suggested:

Let's assume your launch file is called `slam_gmapping.launch` and it's in the `slam_gmapping` package. A quick way to suppress the messages is to launch it like this:

```
roslaunch slam_gmapping slam_gmapping.launch 2>/dev/null
```

I use that trick to launch any launch file which direclty or indirectly includes gmapping.

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2012-05-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [koenlek](https://answers.ros.org/users/4402/koenlek/) on 2014-05-07**:
Hi, I am trying to redirect the stderr and so far, the only way that works is using your 2>/dev/null trick
Now how could you do that in a .launch file? It doesnt seem to accept args in a launch include tag, and for nodes it doesnt seem to work. I could make a bash script for this, but thats ugly...

**Comment by [Sebastian](https://answers.ros.org/users/22737/sebastian/) on 2015-08-18**:
I know this is old koenlek, but did you ever find a solution?

**Comment by [koenlek](https://answers.ros.org/users/4402/koenlek/) on 2015-10-25**:
You can make a bash script e.g. "gmapping_without_output.sh" with just this line:
`roslaunch slam_gmapping slam_gmapping.launch 2>/dev/null`
Put it in a package, usually in a 'script' folder, and you can run in like any node (from cmd line using rosrun, or from launch file using a  block)

**Comment by [Sebastian](https://answers.ros.org/users/22737/sebastian/) on 2015-10-25**:
Thanks for the info.
I just downloaded the source and edited out all the error messages. That works too.

**Comment by [ncharron](https://answers.ros.org/users/30494/ncharron/) on 2017-07-31**:
@Sebastien I know this post is really old, but do you remember which files you needed to change? Thanks

**Comment by [Sebastian](https://answers.ros.org/users/22737/sebastian/) on 2019-02-27**:
Just grep the error message,